# Writing a JSF based spring boot app so that it can also run on a Java EE app server without change

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot is great - we have an app that runs standalone fine, using JAXRS 2, JSF 2.1.6. They versions are irrelevant really, other than they are under our control.

Our corporate deployments are on fully blown Java EE app servers though, so we don't have the option of deploying the app to something simple such as Tomcat or even as a jar with embedded Tomcat.

Trying to get a Spring boot app to work on these ends up being a world of pain, as the Java EE app server will either stop you completely or partially from using different versions of jars to the ones it ships with.

So my question is, is there a magic bullet that allows Spring boot apps to fully blown app servers like WildFly,Glassfish etc. Or what are the general approaches to getting around this issue?

The only one I can think of is to code the application to exactly the same spec as the app server, and then use Maven profiles to ship the jars for the embedded up, but to have them as provided when using them in an app server. Of course this immediately takes away the advantage of Spring not being tied down to a particular version of Java EE.

Comment: Perhaps not the answer you're looking for, but the "magic bullet" is building the Java EE AS yourself and treating it as a resource to be deployed, instead of a thing that's fixed and can't be touched. Of course this only works for open source Java EE servers.

Comment: We can't do that as the primary issue here is that we are (at the moment any rate) tied to deploying to legacy applications servers which we can't change as they to run existing applications.

Ideally we'd deploy just on Tomcat or even as a native boot jar, but for the moment we need to know if we can run boot apps on full JEE app servers.

Comment: What app server are you deploying to? Most have an option to invert the classloader search order so that the contents of your war takes precedence.

Comment: `which we can't change as they to run existing applications` - And that's perhaps your problem right there. I know you can't change this, but to prevent issues like this we always deploy a single app to a single server. IMHO the AS never worked as a replacement for a multi-tasking OS. So many problems people are having with Java EE just vanish if you use an instance of the AS per app.

Comment: We are using Glassfish, which doesn't allow you to override javax packages at all, so we can't use a difference of Jersey. TomEE doesn't have the option to invert the the search order, and JBoss removed this option in Wildfly. In other words, none of the 3 main open source players support it.

Comment: @ArjanTijms not my decision unfortunately, though my recommendation and probably the only sensible option.